# How to filter datagridview using a textbox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, filter

I tired to filter a datagridview using a textbox, the textbox is contained in a tabpage, but it is not working, here is the code :

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "like '%" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%' ";
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

    }
```

Comment: Have you got an exception that is caught?

Comment: Syntax error: Missing operand before 'Like' operator.

Answer (score 18):

`RowFilter` allows you to specify a filter *based on column values*. So the `LIKE` applies to a specific column, not to the whole row. So your condition should be

```
"YourColumn like '%" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%'
```

Also, don't forget that the TextBox could contain the `'` character, so you need to escape it:

```
"YourColumn like '%" + textBox1.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") + "%'
```

Or, cleaner:

```
string.Format("YourColumn like '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));
```

Comment: +1 I think you should clarify "applies to a column" because it could confuse someone later on.

Comment: @Code Monkey, I'm not sure how I could clarify... how would you say it?

Comment: I guess explaining that while it is a `RowFilter`, you are using the value in the `column` to filter for **rows**. That's my suggestion anyways.

Answer (score 4):

try this it is searching for the letter no matter where is that letter ( beginning, mid, or at the end)

```
    private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //this code is used to search Name on the basis of TextBox1.text
            ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Column_Name like '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));
        }
        catch (Exception) 
        {

        }
    }
```

This one searching from the first letter with following the next one by one.

```
try
        {
            ((DataTable)dataGridViewX1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "Column_Name like'" + textBox1.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") + "%'";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
```