# How to filter with textbox the datagrid view without datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, filter

The same question as here: 
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996375/how-to-filter-datagridview-using-a-textbox-in-c)

But in my case my dataGridView1.DataSource is null. 
I use the dataGridView1.Rows.Add function to add rows to the table.
Is it possible to add the filter the column of dataGridView using textbox without DataSource?

Comment: If it's the same question - remove it would be quickly closed as duplicate. If it's not quite the same, please, save a couple of seconds by including the text of the question.

Comment: everything is written above and unserstandable. if they delete then let it be so.

Comment: the value entered in the textbox should act as filter to DataGridView. right?

Comment: yes as a filter to the DataGridView's column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible filter a datagrid that doesn't have a datasource, but I suspect it isn't.

Regardless, an easier solution would be to just give the grid a datasource. Rather than programmatically adding rows to the datagrid, instead create a `DataTable` and add rows to it, then set the grid's data source to that table. Now you can use standard filtering methods.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use this code:

```
if (textBox1.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[column_index].ToString().Trim().Contains(textBox1.Text.Trim()))
                    {
                        row.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                        row.Visible = false;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try linq

```
        private void filter()
        {
            if (this.txtsearch.Text != string.Empty)
                 this.dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Cells["column_name"].Value.ToString() == this.txtsearch.Text.Trim()).ToList().ForEach(row => { if (!row.IsNewRow) row.Visible = false; });
            else
                 this.dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().ToList().ForEach(row => { if (!row.IsNewRow) row.Visible = true; });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Insted of adding rows to the datagridview, create a `DataTable` and add rows to it and bind it to the datagridview. Now you can use TextBox to search.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Column_Name1", typeof(String));
table.Columns.Add("Column_Name2", typeof(String));
......

foreach (var element in list)
   table.Rows.Add(element.Column_Name1, element.Column_Name2, ...);

dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Column_Name1 Like '"+TextBox.Text+"'";
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Rakesh Roa M did was good, but I took it a step further to firstly make it work in VB.NET, but also so that it was case insensitive.
Like you, I'm adding content programmatically as well.
It's certainly not the best way to do this if you have thousands of entries on a DataGridView due to it's inefficiencies, but if the record set is in the hundreds, this should work fine.

```
    If TextBox1.Text IsNot String.Empty Then

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

            If row.Cells("your_column_name").Value.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(TextBox_filter.Text.ToUpper().Trim()) Then
                row.Visible = True
            Else
                row.Visible = False                     
            End If
        Next
    End If
```