# Filtering Datagridview without datasource using linq

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, linq, linq-to-sql

Im using linq-to-sql and trying to filter the datagridview using a combobox. I found this code from  [How to filter with textbox the datagrid view without datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402260/how-to-filter-with-textbox-the-datagrid-view-without-datasource) and tried to use it but on null value it will give me an error and instead of giving me what i need instead its the opposite and removes it from the list

```
if (this.cbx_category.Text != "Category")
                this.dtg_Data.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Cells["category"].Value.ToString() == this.cbx_category.Text.Trim()).ToList().ForEach(row => { if (!row.IsNewRow) row.Visible = false; });
            if (this.cbx_inspector.Text != "Inspector")
                this.dtg_Data.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Cells["inspector"].Value.ToString() == this.cbx_inspector.Text.Trim()).ToList().ForEach(row => { if (!row.IsNewRow) row.Visible = false; });
            else
                this.dtg_Data.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().ToList().ForEach(row => { if (!row.IsNewRow) row.Visible = true; });
```

for diplaying the data

```
var result = (from t1 in db.tbl_item_lists

                          join t2 in db.tbl_uoms
                          on t1.uom equals t2.uom_id into t12
                          from t121 in t12.DefaultIfEmpty()

                          join t3 in db.tbl_mode_procs
                          on t1.mode_of_procurement equals t3.mop_id into t13
                          from t131 in t13.DefaultIfEmpty()

                          join t4 in db.tbl_inspectors
                          on t1.inspected_by equals t4.inspector_id into t14
                          from t141 in t14.DefaultIfEmpty()

                          join t5 in db.tbl_representatives
                          on t1.ofm_representative equals t5.representative_id into t15
                          from t151 in t15.DefaultIfEmpty()

                          join t6 in db.tbl_receivers
                          on t1.received_by equals t6.receiver_id into t16
                          from t161 in t16.DefaultIfEmpty()

                          join t7 in db.tbl_status
                          on t1.status equals t7.status_id into t17
                          from t171 in t17.DefaultIfEmpty()

                          join t8 in db.tbl_categories
                          on t1.category equals t8.category_id into t18
                          from t181 in t18.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new
                          {
                              barcode = t1.barcode,
                              item_name = t1.item_name,
                              description = t1.description,
                              date_procured = t1.date_procured,
                              category = t181.category,
                              part_number = t1.part_number,
                              serial_number = t1.serial_number,
                              batch_number = t1.batch_number,
                              last_borrower = t1.last_borrower,
                              purpose = t1.purpose,
                              date_returned = t1.date_returned,
                              uom = t121.uom,
                              quantity = t1.quantity,
                              mode_of_procurement = t131.mode_proc,
                              price = t1.price,
                              inspected_by = t141.full_name,
                              ofm_representative = t151.full_name,
                              received_by = t161.full_name,
                              contract = t1.contract,
                              proponent = t1.proponent,
                              status = t171.status_desc,
                              delivery_date = t1.delivery_date
                          }).ToList();
            dtg_Data.DataSource = result;
```

I am open to any kind of methods of filtration

Comment: tried doing this and gave me error "Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'void' " and if i remove the ".ToList()" it says "cannot implicitly convert type void to object"

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know what's your `table field name`, `table name`, `filtered field name` in your DB and the name of your `combobox` and your string connection name, you have to change everything which has *[ ]* to the correct name.

`SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [table field name] FROM [table name] where [filtered field name] = ('" + [name of the combobox] + "')", [string connection name]);`

If this don't work to you, please feel free to ask me whatever you want.